# Integral of a function with complex numbers

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

I'm trying to understand [how the Fourier Transform can give the coefficients of epicycloids for any arbitrary closed shape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qS4H6PEcCCA&t=1351s).

Given a "periodic function on the complex plane  $f(t)$" (as I understand it, it's a function that returns a complex number for any $t$), one might find the coefficients of epicycloids (phase, frequency, amplitude) up to a a prescribed order $n$ using

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0} f(t) e^{-nti} dt$$

I'm not sure how I should compute that integral. Let's say I'd do it "manually", by splitting the interval $[0;2\pi]$ into fragments of length $\varepsilon$, and summing the areas of the rectangles (their height would be defined by $f(t)$, for which I know the values on that interval. Would that work ? **Can I simply use the imaginary part of the complex number to get the height of the rectangle** ?

It's actually the first time I see an integral with complex number, and I'm not sure if approaching it the way I described it makes sense or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fourier coefficients are complex numbers, so you expect to get complex numbers.  (It is perhaps helpful to think of these numbers as encoding the magnitude (at all times) and phase (at time $0$) of the corresponding frequency components.

We use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) to rewrite the exponential in your integral in terms of sine and cosine.
$$  \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} = \cos \theta + \mathrm{i}\,\sin \theta  \text{,}  $$
so (using even-odd properties in the last line)
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} (-nt)} 
  &= \cos(-nt) + \mathrm{i}\,\sin(-nt)  \\
  &= \cos(nt) - \mathrm{i} \,\sin(nt)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Now let's rewrite your function to track the real and imaginary parts in separate integrals, turning both integrals into more familiar real integrals.
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi} &\int_0^{2\pi} \; f(t) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} (-nt)} \,\mathrm{d}t  \\
    &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \; f(t) (\cos(nt) - \mathrm{i} \,\sin(nt)) \,\mathrm{d}t  \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \; f(t) \cos(nt) \,\mathrm{d}t - \frac{\mathrm{i}}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \; f(t)\sin(nt)) \,\mathrm{d}t  \text{.}
\end{align*}
These are the [Fourier sine and cosine transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine_transforms).  These two integrands are real valued everywhere, so your thought of partitioning and summing areas of rectangles works.  For each $n$ you will get a complex coefficient $u_n + \mathrm{i}\, v_n$.  To get the amplitude and phase, convert to the [polar representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Complex_numbers), $r_n \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\,\theta_n} = u_n + \mathrm{i}\, v_n$.

---

Let $g = \Re f$ and $h = \Im f$ so that $g$ and $h$ are both real functions and $f(t) = g(t) + \mathrm{i}\, h(t)$.  Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi} &\int_0^{2\pi} f(t) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(-nt)} \,\mathrm{d}t  \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} (g(t) + \mathrm{i}\, h(t)) (\cos(nt) - \mathrm{i} \,\sin(nt)) \,\mathrm{d}t  \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(
\int_0^{2\pi} g(t)\cos(nt) \,\mathrm{d}t
- \mathrm{i}\int_0^{2\pi} g(t)\sin(nt) \,\mathrm{d}t
+ \int_0^{2\pi} h(t)\sin(nt)\,\mathrm{d}t
+ \mathrm{i}\int_0^{2\pi} h(t)\cos(nt) \,\mathrm{d}t
\right)  \text{,}
\end{align*}
and each of these four integrands is a real function so your model of finding area under a curve applies to each.

Comment: Thank you very much for that thorough answer. However I'm still not sure how I will handle the imaginary part in the integral. Let's say I take the final form you wrote, and compute the real part, I'll make a rectangle of width 0.001 and height $f(t) \cos{nt}$ which could be $(7-2i) \cos{5}$ for example. What's that height ? What's that area ?

Comment: I mean, since $f(t)$ will still yield a complex number, I don't get how I could wrap everything up as a sum of rectangles.

Comment: @ArthurAttout : For "how the Fourier Transform can give the coefficients of epicycloids for any arbitrary closed shape", $f(t)$ is real-valued, so the two integrals suffice.  For *general* complex valued $f$, repeat the above, acting on $f$: split to real and imaginary parts, $f(t) = \Re f(t) + \mathrm{i}\,\Im f(t)$, and break each integral into parts yielding four integrals all having real integrands.  Two contribute to the real part of the result, two to the imaginary part.

Comment: With respect to the original video mentioned in the post, $f(t)$ is a function that forms a closed shape, so it yields back complex numbers, for any $t$. I'm not sure what you mean by "$f(t)$ is real-valued".

Comment: @ArthurAttout : Ah.  Had cross-wired that with different work doing the same thing with real-valued polar plots.  Nevertheless, decomposition of $f$ into real (horizontal) and imaginary (vertical) parts and handling the four resulting real integrals seems to be what you want to do.

Comment: Looking back at the answer, I still cannot understand this. The main thing I get stuck with is how to compute the area under the curve of a function $f$ if this function is on the complex plane.

Comment: @ArthurAttout : Have literally written out the prior comment as a post script to the Answer.

Comment: Okay, I didn't get that, when you said "_decomposition of f into real and imaginary parts_", I didn't know one could make that. This makes sense. Appreciate the effort !